# Weld Instance<> and garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jboss-weld

My question will be quite simple : How to avoid JBoss Weld (1.1.5) to keep references to objects produced by Instance ? Typically, the following code :

```
class B{}

class A {
  @Inject private Instance<B> instanceB;

  public B produce(){
    return instanceB.get();
}
```

If I call A#produce(), then the B object won't be garbage-collected before the A object is garbage collected.

Is there any workaround to make it possible for the B object to be garbage-collected, without the A object been garbage-collected ?

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly null instance B then it will be Gc'ed

Comment: It makes sense. But how do I re-inject my instanceB then ? I there no other workaround ? I have something like a hundred instances like this.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot simply set and get the Instance<B> field?